# Can't find ObservableCollection in System.Collections.ObjectModel

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection

Two WPF projects, same machine, browse Collections.ObjectModel

one has ObservableCollections and says

```
// Type: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1
// Assembly: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Assembly location: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll
```

The other (was upgraded from a 3.0 project,) does not and says

```
// Type: System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
// Assembly: mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
```

Why is the second reference to using System.Collections.ObjectModel so different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at 2 different types. Types in different assemblies can be in the same namespace.

Since your upgraded project doesn't include a reference to the System.dll assembly (in 3.0 it was in Windowsbase.dll), it won't have the ObservableCollection. If you add a reference to that assembly, you will have access to that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the end of the System assembly "v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" vs "Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"

That project is set to use the client profile. Go into project properties and select the full .Net 4 profile instead.

Comment: The one with Client Profile has ObservableCollections, the other doesn't. Tried moving the failing project to Client Profile but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple projects. The main project was set to .net 4 but the referenced project was still .net 3.5 and it was referencing the 2.0 mscorlib.