# SortedList<TKey, TValue> not defined in Systems.Collections.Generic using .NET 4.0

Tags: c#

I downloaded a library that uses the generic version of `SortedList`, but when I try to compile it the following error pops up:

`The type or namespace name 'SortedList' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections.Generic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I tried to fix it using the full namespace, `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string, string>` but still no luck, the same error.

I looked up in MSDN and it says that SortedList is supported on .NET 4.0 (the version I am currently using).

Also, my projects references the mentioned namespaces.

This is the code (the error gets repeated more than once, for every reference to SortedList):

```
public class Map
{
    public SortedList<string, Tileset> Tilesets = new SortedList<string, Tileset>();
    public SortedList<string, Layer> Layers = new SortedList<string, Layer>();
    public SortedList<string, ObjectGroup> ObjectGroups = new SortedList<string, ObjectGroup>();
    public SortedList<string, string> Properties = new SortedList<string, string>();
    public int Width, Height;
    public int TileWidth, TileHeight;
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting the client profile, by any chance (project properties)?

Comment: @Oded, Its avaiable under Client profile

Comment: I think, this was defined in the .csproj file: ``<TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>``

Comment: Portable class library, perhaps?

Comment: The output of the project is a Windows Application, is that is what you mean

Comment: Doubt this is the case, but have you referenced System.Collections.Generic?

Comment: @ofstream - The type is declared in `System.dll`.

Comment: *idiot* Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your project's References and select "Add Reference".  Select "Assemblies", and put a tick next to "System".  Click on "OK" and it should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this library built under earlier version of .NET, by chance? Did you change the framework version for the project?

If yes, you may need to add System.dll to the references manually (ref: [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948703/cant-find-observablecollection-in-system-collections-objectmodel))